# User Control при запуске приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

У меня есть три вида формы:

1. Заставка. welcomeScreen
2. Диалог-форма. dialogScreen
3. Общая форма. sizeableScreen

В Programm.cs у меня написано:
Application.Run(new dialogScreen);
То есть при запуске приложения у меня появляется форма dialogScreen.
Мне нужно, чтобы при запуске у меня подгружался пользовательский элемент управления (userControl) в эту самую форму. Но мне нельзя подгружать его в самой форме, так как в дальнейшем у меня этот тип формы используется для других целей. Как мне вставить нужный userControl в загружаемую форму при запуске приложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialogScreen dlg = new dialogScreen();
dlg.Panel.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl());
Application.Run(dlg);
```